# MudBlazor TextChanged Data Conversion

Tags: c#, blazor, crud, mudblazor

I am creating a dynamic form with MudBlazor in order to edit an object. This object has various datatypes. I have no issues creating the form and loading the data using @bind-Value. However, when the values are changed, only the "**string**" datatype works as expected, all others don't. Investigating the "**TextChanged**" callback for MudBlazor, I discovered it is a string type and that explains why only that datatype updated. 
I have also tried to use the "**ValueChanged**". However, this does display the data with its elements.
Is there a way for me to accomplish this by maybe converting the "**TextChanged**" to the specific datatype? Is there any way I may accomplish the results I am looking for in any other form?

```
 @if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
 {
     var stringValue = (string)value;
     <MudTextField T="string" @bind-Value="stringValue" Label="@propertyName" 
         TextChanged="value => property.SetValue(objectToEdit, value)"
         Variant="MudBlazor.Variant.Outlined" AdornmentColor="Color.Warning" 
         Immediate="true" />
   }
 }
 else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime) || property.PropertyType == 
 typeof(DateTime?))
 {
      var dateValue = (DateTime?)(value ?? default(DateTime?));
      <MudTextField T="DateTime?" @bind-Value="dateValue" Format="yyyy-MM-dd" 
               InputType="InputType.Date" Label="@propertyName" 
               TextChanged="dateValue => property.SetValue(objectToEdit, value)"                                                                           
               Variant="MudBlazor.Variant.Outlined" 
               AdornmentColor="Color.Warning"  Immediate="true" />
 }
 else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(int?))
 {
         var intValueNull = (int?)value;
         <MudTextField T="int?" @bind-Value="intValueNull" Label="@propertyName" 
         Variant="MudBlazor.Variant.Outlined"
               TextChanged="intValueNull => property.SetValue(objectToEdit, value)" 
               AdornmentColor="Color.Warning" Immediate="true" />
 }
 else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(short?))
 {
       var shortValueNull = (short?)value;
       <MudTextField T="short?" @bind-Value="shortValueNull" Label="@propertyName" 
       Variant="MudBlazor.Variant.Outlined"
       TextChanged="shortValueNull => property.SetValue(objectToEdit, value)"
       AdornmentColor="Color.Warning" Immediate="true" />
 }
```

Comment: I guess you have several typos. By using TextChanged="intValueNull => property.SetValue(objectToEdit, value) you are setting the original value.
It should rather be TextChanged="intValueNull => property.SetValue(objectToEdit, intValueNull).

Comment: @Uerschel, if I use that variable I get a system.cast exception since "intValueNull" is an int not a string. Any idea how I can cast that?

Comment: You could call a method first instead of setting the value directly

TextChanged="e => IntValueChanged(e)"

private void IntValueChanged(string? stringValue){
  int result;
  bool success = int.TryParse(value,out result);
  if (success)
  {
    property.SetValue(objectToEdit, result);
  }

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this will work and therefore I'm only answering in the comments.

Comment: @Uerschel, your suggestion did not work. I ended up having to do this: `code` TextChanged="intValue => {
          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(intValue.ToString())) {
              property.SetValue(objectToEdit, int.Parse(intValue));
          }
      }" 
`code`

Answer (score 0):

For future reference and if someone decide to use this piece of code. 
The solution was this:

```
TextChanged="intValue => {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(intValue.ToString())) { 
       property.SetValue(objectToEdit, int.Parse(intValue)); 
       } 
    }"
```